# CSS style inside a style - can someone explain this to me

Tags: css

I found a CSS style for setting the arrow position of a popper.js box. The .popper__arrow is inside another style. Can someone explain to me how this works. This is the first time I have seen this used.

The CSS is

```
.popper[x-placement^="bottom"] {
  margin-top: 5px;
  .popper__arrow {
    border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent $popper-bg transparent;
    top: -5px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a CSS preprocessor, either less, sass, etc.

Comment: I know this part is "$popper-bg" but the style in a style ive never seem used like that.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not valid CSS syntax, and it is probably designed to work together with some preprocessor that will take this source and then use it to generate actual CSS.

For example, see [Less.js "nesting" documentation](http://lesscss.org/#nesting).